# A question on Group of homeomorphism of $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Consider $[0,1]$ with the usual euclidean topology. Now $G$ be the set of homeomorphisms from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$. $G$ forms a group under composition. Now, Let $F=\{ f\in G | f(0)=0 \}\ $. Now $F$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

The problem is the following. Suppose $g\in F$ has exactly one fixed interior point. I need a homeomorphism $h \in F$ which is conjugate to $g$ in $F$ such that either of the following happens:

$$  h(x)>g(x)  \hspace{4 cm} \forall x\in(0,1)$$ 
$$  h(x)>g^{-1}(x)  \hspace{3.5 cm} \forall x\in (0,1)$$

I have no idea how to come up with such a homeomorphism satifying either of the two properties and also being conjugate to $g$ in $F$. I suppose that $g$ having exactly one fixed interior point is crucial but I am not sure how to use it!

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: $f(0)=0$ implies that $f(1)=1$, so essentially you are talking about the same set.

Comment: Ha, you're right, my bad.